# publish article to home page and secondary page

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am a joomla convert.  With my old website on Joomla I could publish an article to a specific page as well as the home page.  It would remain on the home page until it was "pushed down" by new articles, but would always be on the specific page in a back up sort of way.  I want to do that here are well.. Let me be a bit more specific...

I have officers at my work place that want to put reports on the website on occasion. When the President posts a report it will post on the front page but also the president page.  I have created a President page on Drupal (7) yet I can't get an article to post to it AND the front page.  I asked this question on another forum and I was rudely directed to look up Taxanomy, which I did and I'm still lost.

Can someone please just direct me to what I need to do to have an article appear on the president page and the home page?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has a "Promoted to front page" check box under Publishing options when you create a new node.

To use this feature, visit `/admin/config/system/site-information` and make sure that the field under "Default front page" is empty.  This will enable your front page to show all content with "Promoted to front page" checked.  Anything you promote to the front page will be both on the front page and also have it's own individual page.

If you have a "President" page that needs to show all the president's articles/reports, you should take a look at [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).  This will be one of your best friends and you will want to take the time to learn how to use it properly.  In short, you would use views to create a block that displays articles authored by the president.  You would be able to display the block wherever needed.

Comment: Patrick, so I go to the president page, and then try to create a new article.  If I click add to front page, it will show up on front page, but it will not show up on president page.   Here's the thing.. I don't want each article to have its own page, I want to have each article to to post on the officer page and the front page.. can I do that?

Comment: Yes, but every node will always have it's own page.  You don't need to make use of the page though.  The part that will let you show all the President's articles on the president page is Views.  If the president etc.. is not creating the articles with their own account, then you need a way to select who the article belongs to.  This is where taxonomy would be useful.  You would create a taxonomy vocabulary that contained President, VP etc.. and then add a taxonomy term reference to your content type.

Comment: woohoo! so now we're getting somewhere.. so where do I find views in drupal 7?  and I really wish I didn't feel as if I was trying to understand russian.. I have no idea how to configure taxonomy.. I've been to the page, but I have no real understanding how to make it work.

Comment: Views is a module that you'll need to install, [find it here](http://drupal.org/project/views).  The taxonomy stuff is really straightforward once you start messing with it.  Basically you just need to `Add Vocabulary` called "officers" -> `Add terms` add a term for each role (president, vp etc..).  You just add the name and save and you're done.  The magic happens when you add a `taxonomy term reference` field to your "Report" content type.  That allows you to target each role when you set up views.